# Binding WPF ContextMenu Submenu to a Collection

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, observablecollection

Trying to get a list of submenu items to bind to an ObservableCollection.

I can get the binding to work on the top level menu. I can also get the items to show in the submenu if I add them in code, which I'd like to avoid.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="tbMenu" >

        <-- Top level menu item -->
        <MenuItem Name="menuLaunchJob" Header="Launch a Job" >
            <-- Display a list of the available jobs in a submenu -->
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>    <-- This doesn't work -->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding}" Header="{Binding jobName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>

        <-- Top level menu item -->
        <MenuItem Name="menuEditJobs" Header="Edit Jobs" >
    </ContextMenu>

    <!-- Globally declared notify icon -->
    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="StatusIcon" 
                    MenuActivation="LeftOrRightClick" 
                    ContextMenu="{StaticResource tbMenu}" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static TaskbarIcon mTaskBar = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        JobsClass jc = new JobsClass();

        Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        InitializeComponent();
        mTaskBar = (TaskbarIcon)this.FindResource("StatusIcon");

        // Job sub-menu list is always the 1st item in the main menu
        MenuItem launchJob = (MenuItem)mTaskBar.ContextMenu.Items[0];
        launchJob.DataContext = jc.mJobs;
    }

    public class JobsClass
    {
        private static JobConfig mJobConfig = JobConfig.Instance;
        public ObservableCollection<JobConfig.JobData> mJobs = new ObservableCollection<JobConfig.JobData>();

        public JobsClass()
        {
            mJobConfig.ReadJobs(); 
            foreach (JobConfig.JobData job in mJobConfig.GetJobs())
            {
                mJobs.Add(job);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <-- Top level menu item -->
    <MenuItem Name="menuLaunchJob" Header="Launch a Job" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="jobName">
```

(Assuming your `{Binding}` is set to your ObservableCollection)

Comment: Are you suggesting that I get rid of MenuItem.ItemTamplate? If I do this, the submenu shows the right number of items, but with no header. Not sure how to make DisplayMemberPath work with the headers of each submenu item.

Comment: OK, got it to work. I needed to convert jobName to a property. Thanks for your help!